# Can't open Eagle software (access denied)

Tags: permissions

I've just installed Eagle software in my Ubuntu 18.04. I extracted the file and place the folder in

> /home/myusername/opt/

then run the eagle app from the folder. For the first time i can go through license agreement, login account and running the app. After exit the app then opening it for the second time (with double click "Eagle" icon) i got an error message said

> "Can't write
>   '/home/myusername/.local/share/Eagle/settings/9.1.3/eaglerc' (access
>   denied)".

But if i open it from terminal from eagle app folder with

> sudo ./eagle

then entering my password, the error not showing anymore. So my question is, how to open Eagle app from the icon without entering password in terminal? Thanks

Comment: try to change ownership as your username `sudo chown <username>:<username> -R /home/myusername/opt/eagle-9.1.3/* ` and run again with `./eagle` on package installation path

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri Thank's for the reply ahmed, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: let i see what the console log said after run `./eagle`?

Comment: I dont really understand how to do it, but is this correct https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4WVpjRYh9p/

Comment: on the pastebin log said "Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x2e0001b specified for 0x2e00019 (Eagle)." that just tell you about window manager warning instead something permission issue like your question

Comment: please provide me more informative about your steps to open Eagle with gnome shell and appears "permission denied" on your output?

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri I've just edit my question, hope it'll make clear the steps you are asking.

Comment: one thing before you open it, remove your sets with type `sudo rm -rf /home/myusername/.local/share/Eagle/` after that change directory of Eagle Package and run `./eagle` without sudo cause that package not your own.

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri Thanks for your help Ahmed. I tried `sudo chown` (as you said earlier) but intead to `/home/myusername/opt/eagle-9.1.3/` i run it on both `/home/myusername/EAGLE/` and `/home/myusername/.local/share/Eagle/` folder which both have a lock icon on it. And now the error doesn't appear anymore. Thanks.

Comment: after you change owned it, is it can launch a Eagle with no output error?

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri Yes, now i can launch it with just double click. Thanks for your help.

Comment: if my answer section can solved your issue, accept it with green checked.

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri Sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Can't write '/home/myusername/.local/share/Eagle/settings/9.1.3/eaglerc' (access denied)".

that log appears cause your don't have owned of your package. change it with `chown`.

one thing before you open it, remove your sets with type

```
sudo rm -rf /home/myusername/.local/share/Eagle/
```

after that, change owned your package.

```
sudo chown <username>:<username> -R /home/myusername/EAGLE/
```

and change directory of Eagle and launch it.

```
cd /home/myusername/EAGLE/
./eagle
```

Hope this helps.